# Is there a uniform bound on the number of solutions to ${\partial p \over \partial x_i} (x_1,...,x_n) = c_i$ outside a set of measure zero?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis

Suppose $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ real variables whose Hessian is not identically zero. Can we say that there is a set $Z \subset {\mathbb R}^n$ of measure zero and a constant $M$ such that for all real numbers $c_1,...,c_n$ the cardinality of the set of $(x_1,...,x_n) \in {\mathbb R}^n - Z$ for which ${\partial p \over \partial x_i}(x_1,...,x_n) = c_i$ for each $i$ is at most $M$? It's possible I might be able to exclude some $(c_1,...,c_n)$ but I'd have be careful what I was excluding.

I've looked around online at resources on systems of polynomial equations and nothing really applied. Also, the above might generalize to systems $p_i(x_1,...,x_n) = c_i$ for $(p_1,...,p_n)$ whose Jacobian is not identically zero, but I only need it in the above situation.

Basically, if this follows from something well-known, or someone has pointers on where to look I'd be appreciative.

Comment: What role does $Z$ play (it is mentioned only once)?

Comment: I think they mean "for all $(c_i) \notin Z$"

Comment: I mean the set of $(x_1,...,x_n)$ outside of $Z$, and I've edited the question. I'd prefer it to hold for each $(c_1,...,c_n) \in {\mathbb R}^n$, but if this isn't possible a carefully chosen excluded set of $(c_1,...,c_n)$ might also serve my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from basic facts about polynomials, to your generalization of a polynomial map $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Since the Jacobian determinant of $F$ does not vanish identically, its zero set $Z$ (the critical points of $F$) has measure 0, since $F$ is a polynomial. Away from critical values, the inverse image is a dimension 0 manifold, i.e. a finite set. Finally, the size of this finite set is bounded by the product of the degrees of the $F_i$'s by Bezout, since it is the intersection of the $F_i^{-1}(c_i)$, each of which is a hypersurface of degree $\deg F_i$

Comment: Can you provide a reference for saying the size of the finite set is uniformly bounded by the degree of $F$? Also, would this extend to real analytic functions?

Comment: Sorry, actually the simplest thing I can think of bounds it by the product of the degrees, which in your case would be $(n-1)^n$. I can try to think if there's a better bound in your case. It definitely does not extend to real analytic, both bc you need to switch Z to the codomain bc of bump functions, and bc there could be infinitely many preimages (consider sine)

Comment: Ok thanks. For the real analytic case it would have to be a local theorem. Is this possible?

Comment: By the way, the reason I was hesitant to use Bezout's theorem is the assumption in that theorem that the zero sets have no common component, which can happen in some cases here. Are you saying there's a way around this?

Comment: The Jacobian determinant will vanish at points where they have a common component. Otherwise the intersection would be codimension less than $n$ and so it couldn't be the preimage of a regular value.

Comment: Re: "the assumption" in Bezout's theorem, see the text of this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/417812/1508

Comment: So Bezout's theorem still gives the desired bound at points that are not in the zero set of the Jacobian? The versions of Bezout theorem I found online just didn't allow common components at all.

Comment: @Zarrax re:locally, depends what you want. Locally on the domain, where you can pick the nbhd after you pick the function -- sure, just pick somewhere where everything is nice. If you have to pick the point before F, I would worry about bump functions

Comment: Basically I start with a function real analytic near the origin and I'd need a neighborhood of the origin where this would work. The neighborhood could be as small as you want though.

Comment: You're only applying Bezout to the preimages of $c$'s outside of $Z$, where there won't be any common components for the reason I mentioned

Comment: Yeah, I'd worry about $e^{-1/x}$ or something similar

Comment: Gotcha. While the $(c_1,..,c_n)$ coming from the critical set are excluded using Bezout, I think I have a way around that in the situation I'm looking at. Thanks.